# Openturns for Telemac2D result file sensitivity analysis

Tags: openturns

I used the Telemac2D software to solve the Shallow Water Equations and got 1000 result files that i want now to post-treat and do some sensitivity analysis with OpenTURNS. The output i mainly want to focus on is the water level. In my case, i can have it's value for different time steps.

My problem is the way of linking the inputs to the output of interest in order to launch a polynomial chaos algorithm, since i don't have an explicit representation of the output by the input (if i had it i could use `ot.SymbolicFunction` or `PythonFunction`).

Answer (score 0):

In the case where the inputs and outputs are known only from a `Sample`, we may use the following constructor:

```
chaosalgo = ot.FunctionalChaosAlgorithm(inputTrain, outputTrain)
```

where `inputTrain` is the input `Sample` and `outputTrain` is the output `Sample`. The two samples must have the same size (but not necessarily the same dimension). In this case, the library performs several steps before fitting the polynomial chaos:

- it fits the multivariate distribution depending on the `inputTrain` `Sample`,
- it creates the multivariate basis depending on the input distribution,
- then it computes the coefficients of the polynomial chaos based on regression.

This way of creating the chaos is presented in the following page:
[Fit a distribution from an input sample](http://openturns.github.io/openturns/master/auto_meta_modeling/polynomial_chaos_metamodel/plot_chaos_build_distribution.html#sphx-glr-auto-meta-modeling-polynomial-chaos-metamodel-plot-chaos-build-distribution-py).